# Rewritting dir based url to custom request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL based dir:

```
https://example.com/subdir/gulp-service/category?parent=666&name=test
```

to query string:

```
?service=gulp-service&file=category&query_string=parent=666&name=test
```

`.htaccess` should work in `https://example.com/subdir/`.
How to write such .htaccess ?

I want to have 2 URLs working:

```
https://example.com/subdir/gulp-service
```

and

```
https://example.com/subdir/gulp-service/category?parent=666&name=test
```

I wrote for service and a file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)$ ?service=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z]+)$ ?service=$1&file=$2
```

in PHP after `print_r($_GET)` I have:

```
Array
(
    [service] => mskip-service
    [file] => category
)
```

How to add missing part of URL to query string?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, So you mean you are hitting link https://group.com/subdir/gulp-service/category?parent=666&name=test
 in browser? Which should be served by which link? Could you please elaborate more on this one?

Comment: What is the URL-path target? In your example it looks like it's the document root? Or should it perhaps rewrite to the same URL-path? `?service=gulp-service&file=category&query_string=parent=666&name=test` - Although, that doesn't look correct as that would result in `query_string`/`parent=666` and `name`/`test`, which doesn't look as if that is the intention? Presumably the `query_string` URL param should contain the entire query string from the initial request? In which case it must be %-encoded like `?service=gulp-service&file=category&query_string=parent%3D666%26name%3Dtest`. (?)

Comment: Yes, sure it can be url encoded, but how to do it to add it to the query string?

Comment: Presumably `666` and `test` in `parent=666&name=test` are variable? Is the value of `parent` always numeric? Are the URL parameters (if present at all) always `parent=<number>&name=<something>`, or can this itself be variable? Your directives imply that the `gulp-service` path-segment and `category` path-segment are also variable?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you require the following in your resulting `$_GET` array, given your second example URL:

```
Array
(
    [service] => mskip-service
    [file] => category
    [query_string] => parent=666&name=test
)
```

If the original query string is entirely variable, then this is a bit tricky since it means the original query string needs to be URL encoded in its entirety (as a URL parameter *value*) before being assigned to the `query_string` URL parameter.

Otherwise, you would get the following (undesirable/mangled) output<sup>***1**</sup>:

```
Array
(
    [service] => mskip-service
    [file] => category
    [query_string] => parent=666
    [name] => test
)
```

So, instead of the following (as in your example):

```
?service=gulp-service&file=category&query_string=parent=666&name=test
```

It *needs* to be URL encoded like this in the eventual target:

```
?service=gulp-service&file=category&query_string=parent%3D666%26name%3Dtest
```

There is no built-in method to do this (the `escape()` function in Apache expressions does not encode `=` and `&` - the two characters that we need to encode!). However, we can effectively search/replace these characters in the query string with an internal recursive loop before rewriting the eventual request.

I would also consider combining the two rules into one. So, both your examples are handled by a single rule. The only caveat with this is that you end up with an empty `file` URL parameter in the first example. And you will always end up with a `query_string` URL parameter, which could be empty when there is no query string on the initial request.

Try the following instead:

```
# Manually encode "=" in query string with search/replace
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=(.+)
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9-]+(/[a-z]+)?$ $0?%1\%3D%2 [N=20]

# Manually encode "&" in query string with search/replace
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)&(.+)
RewriteRule ^[a-z0-9-]+(/[a-z]+)?$ $0?%1\%26%2 [N=20]

# Finally rewrite to desired URL-path
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)(?:/([a-z]+))?$ ?service=$1&file=$2&query_string=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Note that `%` characters that are part of the %-encoded sequence need to be backslash-escaped in the *substitution* string to avoid conflicting with `%N` backreferences.

The `N` flag causes the rewriting engine to immediately start over, using the current result as input. The *value* here indicates the maximum number of loops that will be performed (requires Apache 2.4.8).

By the time the 3rd rule is processed, which does the required rewrite, the original query string (ie. value of the `QUERY_STRING` server variable) has already had all instances of `=` and `&` replaced with `%3D` and `%26` respectively.

---

<sup>***1**</sup> **UPDATE:** However, if the "mangled" output (as mentioned above) is "OK" then the solution is simpler. You just need the 3rd rule from above:

```
# Append the original query string (unencoded)
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)(?:/([a-z]+))?$ ?service=$1&file=$2&query_string=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

You would then get the output:

```
Array
(
    [service] => mskip-service
    [file] => category
    [query_string] => parent=666
    [name] => test
)
```

However, in that case, there wouldn't really be any need for the extra `query_string` URL parameter (which is arguably broken anyway). You could just merge (append) the original query string and manually extract the necessary values. For example:

```
# Merge the original query string
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)(?:/([a-z]+))?$ ?service=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The `QSA` flag appends (merges) the original query string.

To produce the following output, given the example URL:

```
Array
(
    [service] => mskip-service
    [file] => category
    [parent] => 666
    [name] => test
)
```

If you remove the "service" and "file" elements from the array then you can reconstruct the original query string from the remaining name/value pairs.

(Although this may depend on what the backend script is expecting as input.)